# Insert/Update Array data if new or exist

Tags: php, opencart

I have a form which displays existing data that can be edited and also allows for adding new data. How can I update and, if data is new, insert?

On submit I'm sending data like this:

```
 Array
(
  ['0'] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [sort_order] => Sort 1
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Name 1
    )

['1'] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [sort_order] => Sort 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Name 2
    )

['2'] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [sort_order] => Sort 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Name 3
    )
```

My function for insert

```
public function addFilterDamask($data) {
    foreach ($data['filter'] as $filter => $value) {
     $query =   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "damask_name` SET name = '" . $value['name'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$value['sort_order'] . "', filter_id = '" . (int)$value['id'] . "'");
     }

}
```

Comment: PHP's function ```isset``` can help you.

Comment: You could add a where id not in clause to your insert.

Comment: please be more clear what you are asking, it is confusing. you mean you want previous data to exist and also insert a new one?

Comment: Open goal for SQL injection.

Comment: Sayed Mohd Ali , yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to check if MySQL has given it an ID yet, with the assumption you're using `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
$values = [
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'sort_order' => 2,
  ],
];

foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
  if (array_key_exists('id', $value)) {
    // INSERT
    $values[$i]['id'] == ""; // result from ^
  } else {
    // UPDATE WHERE id == $value['id']
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're creating your IDs, you can look into [`REPLACE`](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html), which does what you'd like, but from MySQL's side.

**FYI**: Check out [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) - You should not be using the values directly like you are in PHP, as people can use [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) to change your intentions.